# having trouble finding a solution of the form $u(x,t) = B(t)\cdot e^{\alpha x + \beta t}$ to my PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

given:
$\alpha, \beta$ are constants. find a solution to the following pde in the form $u(x,t) = B(t)\cdot e^{\alpha x + \beta t}$ dependant on their values:
$$u_{tt}  -c^2 u_{xx} = e^{\alpha x + \beta t}$$
the solution given is:
$$\begin{cases} B(t) = \frac{1}{\beta ^2 - c^2\alpha ^2} \quad \alpha ^2 \neq \beta ^2  \\ B(t) = \frac{t}{2\beta} \quad \text{else} \end{cases}$$ I attempted to solve algebriacally by subbing in the attempted solution to the formula then got stuck on this expression:$$B(t)\beta + B'(t)(2\beta - \alpha) + B''(t) = 1$$ and am unsure at all as to how to continue. tried using $B(t) = e^{rt}$ but that led me nowhere, I was hoping you could please help me out as I've been stuck on this for a while. thanks.

Comment: \begin{align} u_{t} &= (B' + \beta B) e^{\alpha x + \beta t} \\ 
u_{tt} &= (B'' + 2 \beta B' + \beta^{2} B) e^{\alpha x + \beta t} \\ 
u_{xx} &= \alpha^{2} B e^{\alpha x + \beta t} \\
\implies u_{tt} - c^{2} u_{xx} &= \color{red}{(B'' + 2 \beta B' + \beta^{2} B - c^{2} \alpha^{2} B)} e^{\alpha x + \beta t} \\
&= e^{\alpha x + \beta t}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your resulting ODE is incorrect. You should have a term with $\beta^2$ and another term with $\alpha^2$ since you're differentiating $u$ twice with respect to each variable.

To actually solve nonhomogeneous linear 2nd order ODEs there's a number of different methods, and usually you'll have to first find the homogeneous solution, i.e. solve the ODE with right hand side $=0$. This essentially consists of making the ansatz $B(t)=e^{rt}$ and finding the roots of the resulting quadratic polynomial. Then use a method like [variation of parameters](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/VariationofParameters.aspx) or [method of undetermined coefficients](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/undeterminedcoefficients.aspx) to find the particular solution, which is added to the homogeneous solution to produce the general solution.

Comment: I'll redo it and continue as suggested, I'll make an edit if it won't work. thank you!